# Android app does not resume when someone comes back after clicking ad

Tags: android, admob

When someone clicks on the ad and comes back to the app the app is not resuming.
I have added `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the mainfest and `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` in the activity declaration in manifest.

I am not getting where am i going wrong.

My code for .java file  is as follows :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener{

 public static int count=0,dispad=0;
 public static LinearLayout lay1;
 private static final Class<?>[] NUMBERS = {First.class};
  protected AdView adView;
    View admobAds;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click on the ad to      
       make        it     disappear" +
            "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

 adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

 lay1=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainlay);

 admobAds = (View) findViewById(R.id.ad);

   //More code 

    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {

    lay1.removeView(admobAds);
    dispad=1;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
   }
```

Comment: For that You need to add this code in onResume Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u should go through this.....
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` as i was not including it in every activity.

when i added this code in the activity my app is now not restarting but the ads are still shown up.